# How to stop getting push notifications when user is logged out?

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hi I am implementing push notifications in Android using xamarin forms.I am getting notifications from notification hub when the user is logged in.But I am getting notifications even when the user is logged out from the app.

Anyone please tell me how to stop getting notification if the user is logged out from the app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which notification you are using local or remote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have registered for push notifications, then once the user is logging out, you could unregister for push notifications.

I am assuming that there should be an API to unregister a device for push notifications from Xamarin.

For example: from [github code example](https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/blob/a8a9969da7bec35871f3f519638e7c328294465d/Azure/NotificationHubs/Android/XamarinTodoQuickStart/GcmService.cs)

```
protected override void OnUnRegistered (Context context, string registrationId)
        {
            if (Hub != null)
                Hub.Unregister ();

            Log.Verbose(PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver.TAG, "GCM Unregistered: " + registrationId);

            createNotification("GcmService Unregistered...", "The device has been unregistered, Tap to View!");
        }
```